# Abstract functions - Dr. Racket

Tags: racket

Develop the predicate `a-student?` that returns `true` if the student has a gpa above 3.7, and use it to 
develop the function `a-students?`, which consumes a list of students, and produces a list of all the 
students who have gpa’s above 3.7. Use filter.

Comment: I was able to do the first part and develop the predicate a-student I am just having problems finding out how to incorporate it in the function a-students.

Comment: We need some information on how you've tried to solve the problem before we can help you. And I'm not even sure what the question is.

Comment: My predicate was (check-expect (a-student? 3.8) true)
(check-expect (a-student? 2.7) false)
(define (a-student? student-GPA)
  (cond [(> student-GPA 3.7) true]
        [(<= student-GPA 3.7) false])).

Comment: I tried solving it using (check-expect (a-students (list S1 S2)) S1)
(define (a-students los)
  (filter a-student? los)) but recieve the error message >: expects a real as 1st argument, given (make-student "Tim" 1234 3.8).  S1 and S2 are previously defined as (define S1 (make-student "Tim" 1234 3.8))
(define S2 (make-student "Bob" 1236 2.7)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the hint says - use [`filter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) in your `a-students` function:

```
(filter (lambda (student)
          (a-student? (student-GPA student)))
        list-of-students)
```

Comment: When I tried to do that before I recieved the error message          >: expects a real as 1st argument, given (make-student "Tim" 1234 3.8).  That is because my predicate was                            (check-expect (a-student? 3.8) true)
(check-expect (a-student? 2.7) false)
(define (a-student? student-GPA)
  (cond [(> student-GPA 3.7) true]
        [(<= student-GPA 3.7) false])) and my check-expect used for my second function was (check-expect (a-students (list S1 S2)) S1).  S1 and S2 were previously defined (define S1 (make-student "Tim" 1234 3.8))
(define S2 (make-student "Bob" 1236 2.7)).

Comment: I am just confused about how to fix this error message.

Comment: @AArce I updated my answer with a possible solution, the problem was that your `a-student?` procedure is receiving the GPA as parameter, not the student. You can either extract the GPA in the `a-students` function (as I did above) or in the `a-student?` predicate, but either way you must extract the GPA somewhere (I'm guessing the procedure to do that is called `student-GPA`)